# SQL - IN Operator get Position

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to get the position (index) of first argument of a list of arguments with a operator as `IN`?

The result I'm looking for is something as next:

```
SELECT 2 IN(2, 3, 1); -- Result I want is 0 but with IN is true
SELECT 3 IN(2, 3, 1); -- Result I want is 1 but with IN is true
SELECT 0 IN(2, 3, 1); -- Result I want is -1 but with IN is false
SELECT 1 IN(1, 1, 3); -- RESULT I WANT IS 0 ,1 but with IN is true
```

Comment: The answer is NO.

Comment: Why exactly you need this. This is a odd request

Comment: IN is not an index operator you select wether or not a value is in a list.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using Postgres

Comment: Create a temporary table with the values and also a rowno column. Join that table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this with a "plain" IN clause, but you can do this with an array and the unnest function:

```
select t.idx
from unnest(array[2,3,1]) with ordinality t(v,idx)
where t.v = 2;

select t.idx
from unnest(array[1, 1, 3]) with ordinality t(v,idx)
where t.v = 1;
```

However, if the value to search for is not in the array, you will get no rows at all.

Answer (score 3):

in postgres can useful function `POSITION`, return first index in string
example:

```
select position('2' in '2,3,1,2') // return 1
```

Comment: And if 22 is added to the list as first item?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use CHARINDEX..

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(10)='22,3,1,2'
DECLARE  @searchkey VARCHAR(10)='2'

select CHARINDEX(','+@searchkey+',',' ,'+ @string+',')-1
```

Comment: And if 22 is added to the list as first item?